How to generate a value between min and max by step, but avoid an arithmetic overflow?
The difficulty lies in the possibility of overflow when subtracting min from max, but using a for loop to calculate one by one is also time-consuming.
    public static long random(long min, long max, int step) {
        if (step <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("step must > 0");
        }
        if (max < min) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid range! min must <= max");
        }

        long range = (max - min) / step + 1;
        long randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(range);
        return min + randomIndex * step;
    }


normal case:
If min=1, max=10, step=2, then the result could be any of them:
1 + 2 * 0 = 1
1 + 2 * 1= 3
1 + 2 * 2 = 5
1 + 2 * 3 = 7
1 + 2 * 4 = 9

edge case:
If min=Long.MIN_VALUE, max=Long.MAX_VALUE, and step=1, then max-min would equals to 0, hence the ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(range) would throw a IllegalArgumentException. This is not I want, the result should range from Long.MIN_VALUE to Long.MAX_VALUE.

Overflow can occur when min<0 and hence max - min is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE.
The obvious answer is to use a BigInteger Otherwise you can check for the exact condition and calculate.
An overflow will occure for the following condition.
if( min < 0 && max>0 && max - Long.MAX_VALUE > min )

In that case range will only be larger than Long.MAX_VALUE if the step==1 or step==2 && min==Long.MIN_VALUE && max==Long.MAX_VALUE. The following equation will cover any other case.
long range = max/step - min/step + (max%step - min%step)/step + 1;

Then our condition becomes.
if( min < 0 && max > 0 && max - Long.MAX_VALUE > min ){
    if( step != 1 ){
        long range = max/step - min/step + (max%step - min%step)/step + 1;
        return range > 0 ? 
          min + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(range)*step 
          : ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong();
    } else{
        long half = max/2 - min/2;
        
        if(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean()){
            //pic low
            return return min + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(half);
        } else{
            long upper = max - half - min;
            return half + min + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(upper);
        }
    }
}

Another way to manage this is to use the built in RandomGenerator.nextLong(min, max)
min%step + ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong( min/step, max/step )*step

This avoids the (max - min ) calculation altogether. The problem is that upper bound is not included. To avoid that we can add 1 to the upper bound.
long upper = max/step == Long.MAX_VALUE ? max/step : max/step + 1;


In the case of step == 1, why not just do nextLong(min, max)?

Ha! Because I didn't go through the API. That might be a good question for the OP where checking if step == 1 would default to that method automatically. The desired range might need to be offset.

Actually, the documentation suggests that it isn't a good method. "The default implementation checks that origin and bound are positive longs. Then invokes nextLong(), limiting the result to be greater than or equal origin and less than bound. If bound is a power of two then limiting is a simple masking operation. Otherwise, the result is re-calculated by invoking nextLong() until the result is greater than or equal origin and less than bound."

Note: for step = 2, min = Long.MIN_VALUE and max = Long.MAX_VALUE  we got range = Long.MAX_VALUE/2 - Long.MIN_VALUE/2 + (Long.MAX_VALUE%2 - Long.MIN_VALUE%2)/2 + 1 == -9223372036854775808 (I would expect a positive number, but long cannot represent it [Long.MAX_VALUE+1])

@user85421 fixed that edge case.

The Math API has several ~Exact methods that can throw an exception on arithmetic overflow.
public static long random (long min, long max, int step) {
  if (step <= 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("step must > 0");
  }
  if (max < min) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid range! min must <= max");
  }
  try {
    long range = Math.subtractExact (max , min) / step + 1;
    long randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(range);
    return min + randomIndex * step; 
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException 
            ("Invalid range! max - min results in arithmetic overflow");
    }        
}

